# Joomla theme module without tables

Tags: joomla, template, table

I copied the 'com_content' folder from the 'beez' template to the html folder of my template.
So now my content displays with divs and without tables.
Now I want to same for my modules I add to the right side of my site.
They are still build with tables and not divs.
Anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok you can just copy all the content from the html folder of the beez theme
next step: change module overrides!